# What is this pollinator's name?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What is the name of this bee pollinating a lemon tree? 
Area: south-central Europe

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an entomologist, but it seems to me that this bee is a [*Xylocopa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpenter_bee), or a carpenter Bee:

[image]
<sup>*Xylocopa iris*</sup>

If this is, in fact, a *Xylocopa*, narrowing it down to the species level will be very difficult, since the Genus has more than 500 species. You could start with one of the most common carpenter bees in Europe, [Xylocopa violacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylocopa_violacea):

[image]
<sup>*Xylocopa violacea*</sup>

However, I believe that this may be in fact *Xylocopa violacea* because of the antennae: you can see a little orange stripe next to the tip of the antenna in the bee of your photo, just like in the bee of the photo above.

Comment: Besides the orange stripe, the "hairyness" of the bee seems more similar in the second photo than in the first one. And the front wings look brown, like in the second photo.

Comment: @bli Indeed. The first photo is just a photo of any bee from the Genus *Xylocopa*. Later, when I found *Xylocopa violacea*, I edited the question but I kept the first photo.